# Show an algorithm with running time O(W(|V|+|E|)) with input a has no polynomial running time

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, analysis-of-algorithms

I would like to show that an algorithm with running time O(W(|V|+|E|)) for a problem with as input a weighted graph $G = (V,E)$ with maximum weight W has no polynomial running time.

The input size of a graph as set of adjacency lists is |V|+2|E|log(|V|). So for a weighted graph the inputsize should be  |V|+2|E|log(|V|) **+|E|log(W)**, since in a weighted graph for each edge you should have a weight of which is maximally W. But how should you then continue to show that the algorithm has no polynomial running time?

Comment: Note that your running time is exponential in $\log(W)$ while your input is linear in $\log(W)$.